# How to use Tkinter python GUI to RUN my webscraper?

Tags: python, tkinter, web-scraping, scrapy

So I have a python webscraper right now that, when ran, gives the user a prompt to pick 1, 2, 3, or all. These options scrape the website/s according to the number. I want to make a python gui that, when the buttons are pressed (or checkboxes) they run the functions associated with 1, 2, 3, or all!
Here is some of my code so you know where I am started off with:

```
from tkinter import * #import statement for dependencies

master = Tk()
var1 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(master, text='Scraper 1', variable=var1).grid(row=0, sticky=W)
var2 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(master, text='Scraper 2', variable=var2).grid(row=1, sticky=W)
var3 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(master, text='Scraper 3', variable=var3).grid(row=2, sticky=W)
mainloop()
```

and here is some of my scraper code so you see what I mean with the options 1, 2, 3, or all:

```
import os, re, scrapy, sys, subprocess, xlwt
from tempfile import TemporaryFile


question2 = input("Which sites? 1 Grainger, 2 instrumart, 3 TruTechTools, 4 FWWebb, or All (1/2/3/All)")
if(question2 == "1"):
    scraper = 1

elif(question2 == "2"):
    scraper = 2
elif(question2 == "3"):
    scraper = 3
elif(question2 == "4"):
    scraper = 4
else:
    scraper = "all"
if (scraper == 1):
    subprocess.call('scrapy runspider graingerScraper.py -o info.json')
    fo = open("info.json", "r")#opens the file for our program to reference. Setting fo to the file, and as a read file variable
    print ("Name of the file: ", fo.name)#we don't need this, its just nice for our output rn
    line = fo.readlines()#creating a String variable = our names.json file
```

Please help me understand how to link the buttons to running actual scraper code!

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. It almost sounds like you're asking us to write the program for you. What part of creating a gui to run your webscraper do you need help with?

Comment: not sure what about my 1000 lines of code means im not making an attempt. @BryanOakley My question more specifically is using the gui buttons im creating, to RUN my scrapers.

Comment: We have no way of knowing that you have 1000 lines of code. We can only go by what you've written in your question. There is plenty of documentation about options for checkbuttons, and how to run code when you click a button. It's unclear what you're asking that can't be answered by reading some existing documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [PySimpleGUI](http://www.PySimpleGUI.org) as a GUI framework. It sounds like you simply need to show some buttons, get those button presses and then call some functions.  That's likely 10 lines of code with PySimpleGUI.  Copy some code from the Cookbook and run it and you'll immediately get an idea of how to use it.

This code will get you started perhaps.  It produces this GUI:
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/13696193/46325549-c3902380-c5c6-11e8-9e8a-75ba89c99bc5.jpg

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[ sg.Text('My Web Scraper') ],
          [ sg.Button('Grainger'), sg.Button('instrumart'), sg.Button('TruTechTools')],
          ]

window = sg.Window('My window').Layout(layout)
button, value = window.Read()

if button == 'Grainger':
    scraper = 1
elif button == 'instrumart':
    scraper = 2
elif button == 'TruTechTools':
    scraper = 3
print(scraper)
```

Comment: thank you! I was setting up my buttons funny and this helped me fix it all up! I got it all working and added some more buttons for scrapers using this methodology. Thank you!